# locate my bash configuration file

Tags: bash

Is there a way to find the name of the bash configuration file that is currently on use. I searched for the .profile or .bashrc but did not find them. However still I can print some of the env variables i.e 
$HOME, $PATH

Comment: Some variables (`HOME` included) are set directly by the shell when it starts, not from any particular configuration file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using one of these `sudo su -`, `bash --login`, `ssh user@host`,
these are considered as login shell,
then you might want to try

1. /etc/profile
2. ~/.bash_profile
3. ~/.bash_login
4. ~/.profile

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables are stored in the each process itself.$HOME and $PATH is stored in the bash process itself.

So,First you have to find process id of your bash process.You can use `ps` command to get the process id of the process.
Then,

```
 cat /proc/your_bash_process_id/environ
```

I hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 4):

As some people said, those files are in the home directory.

| [Operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) | [Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) | [Environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [AT&T Unix (original version)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_UNIX) | `⟨root⟩/usr/⟨username⟩` | [`$HOME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$HOME) |
| Unix-derived | `/var/users/⟨username⟩` `/u01/⟨username⟩` `/usr/⟨username⟩` `/user/⟨username⟩` `/users/⟨username⟩` |  |
| Unix-based <sup>[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#cite_note-5)</sup> | `⟨root⟩/home/⟨username⟩` |  |
| [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD) / [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) ([FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)) | `/home/⟨username⟩` or `/usr/home/⟨username⟩` |  |
| [SunOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SunOS) / [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)) | `/export/home/⟨username⟩` |  |
| [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) | `/Users/⟨username⟩` |  |
| [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) | `/data/media/⟨userid⟩` |  |
| Microsoft Windows NT | `⟨root⟩\WINNT\Profiles\⟨username⟩` | [`%USERPROFILE%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25USERPROFILE%25) [`%HOMEDRIVE%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25HOMEDRIVE%25) [`%HOMEPATH%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25HOMEPATH%25) |
| Microsoft Windows 2000, XP, and 2003 | `⟨root⟩\Documents and Settings\⟨username⟩` |  |
| Microsoft Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10, and 11 | `⟨root⟩\Users\⟨username⟩` |  |

(Table from [Wiki article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory))

I'll tell you here how to find it for Windows 10.

You can quickly find and open some of those locations with the following commands (using bash console):

- `cd ~` ← It will take you to your home directory.
- `pwd` ← will print the path to your current directory (can use the above together: `cd ~; pwd`)
- `ls -a` ← It will display files and folders, both visible and hidden.
- `explorer .` ← It will open the home folder in Windows Explorer, which can be really useful. Look for the file/folder you need. Move to it using:
- `cd folder-name` or open the file in the text editor using `notepad file-name`. For your case, you should find and open `notepad .bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

Those files are in the user's home directory.

> $HOME/.profile
>
> $HOME/.bashrc

Comment: already checked, but nothing on this machine. However still I can view the $PATH content !!!!

Comment: So the ones used by your system might be /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc which source $HOME/.profile (~/.profile) and $HOME/.bashrc (~/.bashrc).