# bash alias - running two commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How do I make an alias in my `.bashrc` such that I can run two commands with arguments?

For example, compile source and run.

```
gcc-run -lm example.c
```

would run

```
gcc -lm example.c
./a.out
```

The closest I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756756/multiple-commands-in-an-alias-for-bash) but it doens't have any arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass an argument, you can't use an alias. You need to use a shell function. It sounds like you want something similar to

```
gcc-run () {
    gcc "$@"
    ./a.out
}
```

Comment: Another small related question. How would I then pick out individual arguments to use in an if-else statement?

Comment: the shell functions are simuliar as "normal" shell program, you can use `$1` `$2`... for individual arguments.

Comment: You might actually want to make sure that compilation was successful.  `gcc-run () { gcc "$@" && ./a.out; }`