# Multi-line alias with shell expansion hangs for another argument

Tags: bash, shell

Hel‌lo! Before I begin, my question is not a duplicate of this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071263/multi-line-alias-in-bash
or this:
[Multiple commands in an alias for bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756756/multiple-commands-in-an-alias-for-bash/756772). And I've read the answers thoroughly.

My issue is that when I assign a variable inside a multi-line alias, something goes wrong in which it causes the shell to wait for another argument.

Here's a working alias:

```
$ alias alias1='var1="$(date)" ; echo $var1'
Wed Jul 28 18:07:37 +0230 2021
```

But if I write it in multiple lines, shell waits for another argument:

```
$ alias alias1='var1="$(date)"
> echo $var1'
$ alias1
$ hello
Wed Jul 28 18:10:28 +0230 2021 hello
```

I know the issue is with `date` but I don't understand what is happening.

I tried putting `;` at the end of the first line, and it didn't fix the issue, but I put `&&` and it fixed the issue, `\` also fixed the issue which is weird to me because `\` is for line continuation:

```
$ alias alias1='var1="$(date)" \ 
echo $var1'
$ alias1
Wed Jul 28 18:12:47 +0230 2021
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on, but you can fix it by using a function instead of an alias.

Comment: Why do you think the backslash result is weird? It makes it ignore the newline, so it's like a single command `var1="$(date)" echo $var1`

Comment: @Socowi But as I've said, I read all the answers on the links I put, they also said that functions are better, but I'm asking this question for learning purposes!

Comment: @Barmar Because they are separate commands, thus they should not be on the same line and should be on different lines!

Comment: Yes, but you're also allowed to put variable assignments at the beginning of any command. Try it as an ordinary command line.

Comment: Aliases are executed in a weird way because of the way they substitute into the command line.

Comment: Ah, I see, Thanks very much. If you could please write an answer, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: It would be a better choice to make this a function instead of an alias in the first place. `alias1() { var=$(date); echo "$var1"; }` -- still works if you change the `;`s to newlines, too.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Bash 5.1.8.

Comment: @oguzismail yes exactly, I get different results on different systems. Read vdavid's answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing that never failed me so far is curly braces.

```sh
alias alias1='{ var1="$(date)"
echo $var1; }'
```

Make sure to add a space character after the opening curly brace and before the closing one. If there is a command one the same line of the closing brace, make sure to add a `;` as shown above.

You can use newlines to get rid of that ugly `;` if you wish to do so:

```sh
alias alias1='{
var1="$(date)"
echo $var1
}'
```

You can do the same with parentheses `()` and actually the syntax is more forgiving, e.g. you don’t need the extra space characters nor the final semi-colon, but you don’t have access to variables that you have assigned inside your alias.

```sh
alias alias1='(var1="$(date)"
echo $var1)'
```

**TL;DR**: use curly braces if you want to have access to the variables after the alias is called, otherwise use parentheses to prevent your variables from leaking

### Side note

I haven’t been able to find a source for explaining why it behaves like that, but multi-line aliases may respond differently from one system to another. In your case it seems to wait for user input. I have a CentOS distribution which works but also displays the prompt string:

```
[user@localhost tmp]$ alias alias1='var1="$(date)"
> echo $var1'
[user@localhost tmp]$ alias1
Wed Jul 28 18:09:32 CEST 2021 date printf \033]0;%s@%s:%s\007 user localhost /tmp
```

On my Cygwin embedded in MobaXterm, it simply displays nothing.

Bottom line: use multi-line aliases at your own risk.