# MATLAB logical operators: && vs &

Tags: matlab, operands

If I want to ensure that an `if` statement only executes if BOTH of two conditions are true, should I be using `&` or `&&` between the clauses of the statement?

For example, should I use

```
if a == 5 & b == 4
```

or

```
if a == 5 && b == 4
```

I understand that the former is elementwise and the latter is capable of short-circuiting but am not clear on what this means.

Comment: The MATLAB documentation discusses operator short-circuiting [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-40063.html#f0-39129), the `&&` and `||` operators [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) and the element-wise operators `&` and `|` [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a scalar boolean condition I'd recommend you use `&&`.  Short-circuiting means the second condition isn't evaluated if the first is **false**, but then you know the result is false anyway.  Either `&` or `&&` one will be true only if both sides of the expression are true, but `&` can return a matrix result if one of the operands is a matrix.

Also, I believe in Matlab comparisons should be done with `==`, not with `=` (assignment).

Comment: Incidentally, why wouldn't you want an AND condition to short-circuit? Since it's only going to be true if all the conditions are true, surely if the first condition is evaluated and turns out to be false, evaluating more is just a waste of processing power..?

Comment: @CaptainProg sometimes you want to evaluate functions for the side effects

Comment: Sverre, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @CaptainProg see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445867/why-would-a-language-not-use-short-circuit-evaluation