# Substring in Where clause

Tags: sql, substring, varchar

Below is my query, I am looking to pull records where only the substring value (which will be YYYY) is less than current year - 25 years....  and I should mention that this field is varchar and probably needs to be converted which I haven't been able to do successfully either.

```
SELECT 
            AccountNumber,
            LoanPrimeLongName,
            convert (varchar,LoanOpenDate,103)LoanOpenDate,
            LoanOriginalBalance,
            LoanBalance,
            LoanInterestRate,
            LoanRemainingTermMonths,
            LoanDelqDays,
            LoanDescription
FROM 
            ARCU.ARCULoanDetailed 
WHERE 
            (((LOANTYPE = '15'          OR
            LOANTYPE = '16'         OR
            LoanType = '17')            AND
            LoanStatus = 'Open')        AND
            ProcessDate = (CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)-1)) AND
            (SUBSTRING (loandescription,1,4) not like '%[^0-9]%')

ORDER BY AccountNumber
```

Comment: I am new to this, unsure how to post query in better format

Comment: Select the text, then either press the `{}` button, or press `ctrl+k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't know which RDBMS you are using, I'm going to go with the simplest answer. This assumes you're using MSSQL.

Use the [ISNUMERIC()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function to determine if `SUBSTRING(loandescription,1,4)` is actually a number. If it is, then you can cast/convert it at that point and compare it to the "year" you're interested in. IE:

```
        ...
        ProcessDate = (CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)-1)) AND
        (ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(loandescription,1,4)) = 1 AND 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(loandescription,1,4) AS INT) = (YEAR(GETDATE()) - 25))
```

Due to boolean short circuiting, if the first 4 characters AREN'T numeric, then it won't bother casting to compare. Same rule applies with other RDBMS systems (such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc), but the methods might be a bit different. In fact, I don't think MySQL or PostgreSQL even have the `ISNUMERIC` function, meaning you need to find other ways (Regex) to test.

Comment: Because of how the SQL Server optimizer works (most SQL optimizers do *not* use short-circuiting, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1445911/109122), this isn't necessarily safe. You need to put the test(`ISNUMERIC`) in a `CASE WHEN` conditional expression and then hide the usage (`CAST`) in its `THEN` clause to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 'YYYY' field is `(SUBSTRING (loandescription,1,4) not like '%[^0-9]%')`:

```
AND CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (loandescription,1,4) not like '%[^0-9]%' 
            THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(loandescription,1,4)AS INT 
            ELSE YEAR(GETDATE()) 
     END < YEAR(DATEADD(year,-25,GETDATE()))
```

You need the `CASE` statement since the year isn't always populated, and text values won't `CAST` as `INT`.  Then you use the `GETDATE()` function in conjunction with `DATEADD()` to add in your 25 year criteria.

Comment: I am pulling a substring form the description EXAMPLE  '2005 Chevrolet Camaro'  I am trying to substring the year, and then pull only values 25 years old.  I keep getting the error that "conversion failed when converting the varchar value "HOME" to data type int       I apologize for being vague, I am not sure what all information will help, especially without knowing the database, I have some background in SQL but am not a guru in it yet...

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like the problem is that your year is not always populated. See updated.