# How does || and && return value notations work?

Tags: bash

Many use the notation below in scripting languages, but I don't quite understand how it works.

```
~$ false || echo "aa"
aa
~$ true || echo "aa"
~$ true && echo "aa"
aa
~$ false && echo "aa"
~$
```

Are both sides executed first, and then their return values evaluated?

What would be a more straight forward way to write these?

Is `||` an `XOR`?

Comment: `||` is just `or`, which has short-circuiting functionality

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: `||` isn't `XOR`, but `OR`. Unlike `OR`, `XOR` can't be short-circuited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `&&` and `||` to control the evaluation is a very fundamental thing in
programming. As many already answered, they are using "Short Circuit Evaluation".
In some languages they are the same as `and` and `or`, but not in all. In e.g.
Ruby they do **not** mean exactly the same (as I know).

> What would be a more straight forward way to write these?

You could say that using `&&` and `||` instead of `if ... else` is lazy
programming, but some people would say that using `&&` and `||` structure is
the most straight forward.

**If** you will have an alternative (or a way of understand this better):

```
expr && echo "aa"

# is the same as

if expr; then
  echo "aa"
fi
```

and

```
expr || echo "aa"

# is the same as

if ! expr; then
  echo "aa"
fi
```

and

```
expr && echo "yes" || echo "no"

# is the same as

if expr; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

and of course a mix

```
if this && that; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

The "Short Circuit Evaluation" is a very important rule, and in some
situations the code is depending on this.
In this example (from VIM, but it's the same in many languages) there would be an exception if it doesn't work:

```
if exists("variable") && variable == 3 ...
```

If both sides was evaluated before deciding the result there would be an
exception if `variable` isn't defined.

There have been some bad designed languages where both sides of e.g. `&&` was
evaluated before the result was given, they were not so fun to use.

So:

```
if you like it; then
  use it && be happy
else
  use it || be happy
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

`||` is an OR (not an XOR).

With scripting (as with source code) the right-side is only evaluated if necessary.

with `||` the RHS is evaluated if the LHS evaluates to false or 0. With `&&` the RHS evaluates only if the LHS evaluates to true.

That is because true || anything is always true so there is no need to evaluate the RHS. And false && anything is always false.

See also [Benefits of using short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89154/benefits-of-using-short-circuit-evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

`||` and `&&` are lazy in all the languages you listed.

The way it works is that the expression is evaluated left to right. In the case of `||`, the value of the entire expression is the value of first argument which is not "false-y" (or the last argument, if all of the arguments are false-y) will be the value of the expression.

Comment: Except that in Python `||` is `or` and `&&` is `and`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty simple.

The left side is evaluated first every time and the right side is evaluated if required.

In the first case, LHS is `false`, so the result of the expression depends on the RHS as it is an `OR` operation. So the right side is evaluated/executed.

In the second case, LHS is `true`, and the result of the `OR` operation will be `true` regardless of what is there in the RHS, so the RHS is never evaluated/executed.

Same thing happens with the `AND` operation. It needs to evaluate the RHS only if LHS is `true` as in the 3rd statement.